# How to set x axis values in a heatmap

Tags: matlab, heatmap

I'm trying to display a heatmap of temperatures in the upper strata of the earth. Is there a way not to display an axis label for every cell, but instead display a fixed amount of labels?

I tried setting the axis labels, but I didn't figure out how to do this with fewer x-labels than columns:

```matlab
time = linspace(1,t_iter*dt,10);
depth = linspace(1,z_iter*dz,10);
heatmap(time,depth,T, 'Colormap', jet, 'GridVisible', 'off');
```

[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9G1ic.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set ticks manually

```
h = heatmap(time,depth,T, 'Colormap', jet, 'GridVisible', 'off');
set(h,'XTick',[ 1 2 3 ])
set(h,'XTickLabel',[ 1 2 3 ])
set(h,'YTick',[ 1 2 3 ])
set(h,'YTickLabel',[ 1 2 3 ])
```